# Is their a functional form of updating state using useState hook that contains updated props along with previous state?

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state, setstate

In a class based React component, we can define handler function using functional form of setState like :

```
const handleClick =()=> {this.setState((prevState,updatedProps)=>({// return some object }))}
```

where, the two arguments represent previous state and updated props passed to this component.

Similarly, we have a functional form to set state in functional component using useState hook like this:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

const handleClick =()=> {setCount(c=>c+1)}
```

But as we can see, this functional form in useState hook lacks second argument representing updated props

Has this been intentionally left by React development team?
How can we access the updated props along with previous state while setting state in useState hook?
Actual code depicting the problem : [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/testerbox-fiit4)

Just alternate between two Counter components( one is functional while other is class based) by importing one at a time in App component.

Comment: Use `useRef` to make a custom hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state

Comment: @morganney - Hey!! I am looking for latest props coming from parent component.
Though it is possible to have the latest props as well using useRef , i am asking why React team left it from the functional signature of set State using hook?

Comment: So store those in a `ref.current`. The solution you need is shown in the docs. As to why the React team did not include a `usePrevious` hook I couldn't tell you, but they did supply `useRef` so I'd just use that.

Comment: @morganney -
I am not looking for usePrevious hook as that gives me previous value of prop or state. Rather am looking for latest props since setState is  asynchronous. 
To have latest props instead ,i can still use ref:
 ref.current = props;
 as the first line inside functional component ( and not inside useEffect since inside useEffect it will refer to previous props).

Comment: if you're looking from the latest props, then why don't you just use the `props`???

Comment: @IamL -  If you could look into the code shared , you will find that before setting state in the child component (Counter component), the parent component ( which passes new props on its own set State) also re-renders by virtue of its own setState.
So I want to ensure that when I set State the Child component using props from parent (App component), I always get the latest.
I can achieve it if my Counter component is class based but not if it is functional. This is because  this.setState has two arguments, one for previous state and second for that updated prop.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just trigger the count inside the useEffect like so (I modified your FunctionalCounter like so), read comments inside code.

(quite a hacky way so it will only change if the prop value was triggered by click)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function FunctionalCounter(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(100);
  const [shouldTrigger, setShouldTrigger] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (shouldTrigger) {
    setCount((c) => c + props.fromParent);
    setShouldTrigger(false);
  }
}, [props.fromParent,shouldTrigger]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3> The counter value is {count}</h3>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          props.handleUpdate();
          setShouldTrigger(true);
        }}
      >
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Other way that I can think of is returning the value on `props.handleUpdate();` so you can use it without relying on parent like so:

App.js

```
  const handleUpdate = () => {
    const newVal = appVar + 1
    setAppVar(newVal);
    return newVal;
  }
```

FunctionalCounter.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function FunctionalCounter(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(100);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3> The counter value is {count}</h3>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const newCount = props.handleUpdate();
          setCount(newCount);
        }}
      >
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This works. Even I had tried it but the problem with this solution is that this will set the count whenever that parent prop changes, whether i click on the button on child component or not. I want to do it only when the button is clicked.

Comment: @gamebecks I edited the answer and also gave an additional alternative solution.

Comment: Both of the solutions in your edited response complete the requirement. But there is one caveat in first as it causes one additional rerendering due to setCount inside useEffect against just one in Class component case.
The second one seems appropriate.
This brings me back to my original question that why React Team didnt supply the useState hook with updated props as second argument akin to class based setState?

Comment: @gamebecks not sure and tbh I never really encountered such situation as your problem in my 6 years of react experience. Just realize this one as well in this particular question.